# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, recaptcha

I'm working on Spring-MVC Dynamic application.

Controller:

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemp;

    @RequestMapping(value="//errorpage")
    public ModelAndView errorPage(HttpSession session)
    {
        if(session.getAttribute("username")==null)
        {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        }
            return new ModelAndView("errorpage");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView checkUser(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session,ModelAndView model) throws ParseException
    {
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
        String response = request.getParameter("g-recaptcha");

        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        System.out.println("ReCaptcha: "+response);

        String url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        String params="?secret=6LcHGKQUAAAAANcsmAeYQyLGK9GyazkQ7vebU-Qx&response="+response;
        ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse=restTemp.exchange(url+params,HttpMethod.POST,null,ReCaptchaResponse.class).getBody();

        if(reCaptchaResponse.isSuccess())
        {
            System.out.println("Captcha Success");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Captcha Unsuccessful");
        }
}
```

ReCaptchaResponse.java

```
package com.recaptcha;

public class ReCaptchaResponse 
{
    private boolean success;
    private String challenge_ts;
    private String hostname;
    //getter and setter methods
}
```

NOTE: getting null value of reCaptcha response.

getting error message on screen:

Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]

Errors:

```
May 29, 2019 12:13:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [VerilogEvaluation] in context with path [/VerilogEvaluation] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:572)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:448)
    at com.controller.WelcomeController.checkUser(WelcomeController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```